# Membership Levels in XCart: Keeping Products Still Visible

Tags: php, membership, x-cart

I have a question about membership levels in XCart. I know you can make products hidden using the membership levels but I'm wondering if it is possible to keep the products visible but make it so that they cannot be purchased by a customer without certain membership levels.

The issue I'm having is that I have a client who is using XCart and they have a store but they only want their students and staff to have the ability to purchase from the store. More or less as an incentive to enroll. So if you view the store as a regular customer, you still see the products but you can't click on a "Buy Now" button. Would it have to do with conditional statements implemented on the "buy now" buttons?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default this is not possible. But I guess this extras ( extras is a popular modification available at a lower price) for $39 may help you to achieve what you describe:

http://mods.x-cart.com/Hidden-Product-Prices.html

This is not exactly what you request, it does not allow to configure the possibility to purchase the product depending on the membership. But it does encourage the customer to register.

I hope it helps.